# Limitation of images numbers for PHPickerConfiguration?

Tags: swift, picker, photokit

Is it possible to set a limit for images numbers for PHPickerConfiguration? (Not selectionLimit!) I want my users can upload up to five images.

Comment: Why `selectionLimit` does not work for you? If users cannot select more then 5 they cannot do anything more. Would you elaborate more on details?

Comment: @Asperi user can easily upload 1000 pic just one by one.

Comment: Then it is not a picker responsibility but your app logic.

Answer (score 1):

setting to 0 means infinit

```
var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration()
configuration.selectionLimit = 0
configuration.filter = .images
```

Comment: Not selectionLimit. I was talking about upload limitation, not for selection.